# Properly import module with some definitions only visible with qualified names

Tags: haskell, coding-style

Suppose I have an module `A` with names `b`, `c` defined.

Now I wish to import A in some way and the following names should be accessible:

- `A.b`
- `A.c`
- `c`

where unqualified name `b` is hidden.

The method I tried is to import A twice in two ways:

```
import A hiding (b)
import qualified A (b)
```

But it doesn't seem to achieve the effect described above. So what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
import A (c)
import qualified A
```

Or

```
import A hiding (b)
import qualified A
```

which should only give you access to `c`, then everything inside `A` using the qualified syntax.  If you're testing this in GHCi, remember that GHCi has some extra special stuff to allow it more access inside a module that it loaded from source since it's primary use is exploration and debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I do this in ghci, it warns me: `This binding for ‘b’ shadows the existing binding`? So do you mean I should ignore this warning? Suppose I have then defined `b` in my source file.

Comment: @ShouYa yeah, probably. Again, this won't really be testable from ghci, since it has more ability to look inside a source file. If you had this installed to your system as a compiled library, ghci wouldn't be able to see the extra b in there, it's only when it has access to the source code directly (I am 99% sure of this, anyway)

Comment: I yet thought I was doing something wrong. If you're certain like that, I would feel more easy then :) Thank you.